# colSds does not work since the last matrixstats update in R

Tags: r

It seems like the colSds is not working since the last update in matrixStats (v0.10.0, 2014-06-07). It worked for me before, but now it returns an error message:

> Error: no applicable method for 'colCounts' applied to an object of
>   class "data.frame"

Here is an example:

```
library(matrixStats)
data(mtcars)
colSds(mtcars)
```

I use R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10) on windows 7(x64). Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit).
Does anyone have a clue what went wrong, and what can I do with it?

Thanks,
Tamas

Comment: On linux, R 3.1.0 it works fine.  colSds(mtcars)
        mpg         cyl        disp          hp        drat          wt 
  6.0269481   1.7859216 123.9386938  68.5628685   0.5346787   0.9784574 
       qsec          vs          am        gear        carb 
  1.7869432   0.5040161   0.4989909   0.7378041   1.6152000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like colSds only works on matrices.  This works for me.

```
colSds(as.matrix(mtcars))

 mpg         cyl        disp          hp        drat          wt 
6.0269481   1.7859216 123.9386938  68.5628685   0.5346787   0.9784574 
   qsec          vs          am        gear        carb 
1.7869432   0.5040161   0.4989909   0.7378041   1.6152000
```